# Cardboard Bazel BUILD files

Tags: google-cardboard, bazel

Now that Bazel is open source, can you include a BUILD file in the cardboard SDK repo? Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe internally all Google projects use Bazel (Blaze) so it shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to file this as a feature request in the [Cardboard project](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/issues). Internal BUILD files look a little different than the external ones, so even if there are BUILD files for it internally (which I'm not positive there are), it isn't exactly trivial.